# Updating contextual array in Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I have this simple piece of code:

```
function test(){
   var test_array = []
   return function(i){
     test_array.push(i);
     alert(test_array.length);
   };
 }
```

Since the context is bound to the closure I was expecting the code to update the lenght of the array each time I call the anonymous function. However this is not happening. If I call the closure multiple times like this:

```
test()(1);
test()(2);
```

The alert is always showing a length of 1.
Could you explain me why?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call to `test` creates a *new* execution context containing a *new* array and a *new* function closing over that context (including the array).

If you save a reference to the function `test` returns and then call that same function repeatedly, it will update the array created by the call to `test` that created the function, you'll see what you expect:

```
var f = test();
f(); // 1
f(); // 2
```

Or of course, you can have more than one:

```
var first = test();
var second = test();

first();  // 1
first();  // 2
first();  // 3
second(); // 1
first();  // 4
```

Comment: A detailed solution is available at [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html)